# Dynamic CRM 2013 Pre-Operation plugin for Quote Products not executed

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

EDIT.

Problem is solved. I created new project without underscores in its name. So, after unregistered old assembly and registered new assembly, plugin is executed. Also in new project I signed dll with key without password. Helpfully mystery is gone. Thanks everyone for Your time.

==========================================================================

Context of plugin is: sales department is creating quotes and adding products to quotes. In quotes there is a column LineItemNumber. So, when person wants to move a product to 3 place, it just changes LineItemNumber to 3 (example from 8). So, plugin is rewriting LineItemNumbers. So, 3 goes to 4, 4 => 5 and so on.
here is plugin code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

namespace plugin_fix_line_item_number
{
    public class FixLineItemNumbers : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            // Get a reference to the Organization service.
            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            if (context.InputParameters != null)
            {

                //Get Target - includes everything changed
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                //Get Pre Image
                Entity image = context.PreEntityImages["PreImage"];

                // post image
                //Entity imagePost = context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];

                int? new_lin = null; //lineitemnumber
                int? old_lin = null;

                if (entity.Attributes.Contains("lineitemnumber"))
                {
                    new_lin = (int)entity.Attributes["lineitemnumber"];
                    old_lin = (int)image.Attributes["lineitemnumber"];

                    if (new_lin < 1) return; 

                    if (new_lin != null && old_lin != null)
                    {
                        if (new_lin != old_lin)
                        {
                            bool pieskaitiit = true; //by default, count lineItemNumber up
                            EntityCollection products = new EntityCollection();
                            QueryExpression q = new QueryExpression("quotedetail");
                            q.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "lineitemnumber" });
                            q.Criteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;

                            Guid quote_id = ((EntityReference)image.Attributes["quoteid"]).Id;

                            q.Criteria.AddCondition("quoteid", ConditionOperator.Equal, quote_id);
                            if (new_lin > old_lin) // 2 pozīcija pārtop par 5    2 => 5
                            {
                                q.Criteria.AddCondition("lineitemnumber", ConditionOperator.LessEqual, new_lin);
                                q.Criteria.AddCondition("lineitemnumber", ConditionOperator.GreaterThan, old_lin);
                                pieskaitiit = false; // here must count down
                            }
                            else{ // 5 pozīcija pārvietojas uz otro    5 => 2
                                q.Criteria.AddCondition("lineitemnumber",ConditionOperator.LessThan, old_lin);
                                q.Criteria.AddCondition("lineitemnumber",ConditionOperator.LessThan, old_lin);
                            }
                            products = service.RetrieveMultiple(q);
                            foreach(Entity e in products.Entities)
                            {
                                int lin = e.GetAttributeValue<int>("lineitemnumber");
                                if (pieskaitiit) lin++; else lin--;
                                e.Attributes["lineitemnumber"] = 9;
                                service.Update(e);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }//
    }
}
```

I have registered plugin and it see all variables witch is required by plugin. I disabled plugin  step `ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose: Update of  any Entity` because if it is enabled, when i save quoteProducts form, then i got error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: An error occurred. Contact a system administrator or refer to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK troubleshooting guide.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220891</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>OperationStatus</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">0</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>SubErrorCode</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">-2146233088</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>An error occurred. Contact a system administrator or refer to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK troubleshooting guide.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2014-12-11T15:38:01.0167124Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

[ActivityFeeds.Plugins: ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose]
[6213e0c9-2881-e411-9ac4-0050569aa6cf: ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose: Update of  any Entity]


</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

I searched google and found this: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/90521/170686.aspx
So, if i disable `ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose` step then, when saving form, no changes in database are made (by plugin). Even if i add line `throw new Exception("Mega error");` before first if, also then nothing happens, Form is saving data but plugin not executed.

I already tried plugin profiler too (http://inogic.com/blog/2012/06/how-to-debug-plugins-using-profiler/). I runs just fine. If `ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose` step is disabled and then run profiler and then debug, then exception is thrown.

This plugin is only one, witch is executed Pre-Operation.

What else I can look into? Some system configuration issues? Maybe someone have some ideas what else I can try. Thanks.

Comment: Is the end goal just to have the quote line items ordered in a particular way?

Comment: @JasonFaulkner , yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. I created new C# project without underscores in its name. So, after unregistered old assembly and registered new assembly in crm, plugin is executed. Also in new project I signed dll with key without password. Helpfully mystery is gone. Also `ActivityFeeds.Plugins.ActivityClose: Update of  any Entity` step I leave disabled.
Thanks everyone for Your time.